# adding node app to aws

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express

I'm adding my node app to aws, but it won't load the actual page. I think there's something wrong with my server.js file, because if i load a boiler node app and ssh into my aws and run it the application works. However when I run mine the connection times out or i get an error like

```
events.js:183
  throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
  ^
Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000
   at Object._errnoException (util.js:992:11)
at _exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1014:20)
at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1355:14)
at listenInCluster (net.js:1396:12)
at Server.listen (net.js:1480:7)
    at Function.listen (/home/ubuntu/memory-box/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:618:24)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/memory-box/server.js:21:5)
at Module._compile (module.js:652:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:693:10)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
```

my server.js file looks like

```
var express = require('express'),
app = express(),
port = process.env.PORT || 3000,
mongoose = require('mongoose'),
Task = require('./api/models/memoryBoxModel'), //created model loading here
bodyParser = require('body-parser');
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise; mongoose.connect('mongodb://username:password@ds125402.mlab.com:25402/memorybox', { useNewUrlParser: true });

app.use('/uploads', express.static('uploads'))
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());


var routes = require('./api/routes/memoryBoxRoutes'); //importing route
routes(app); //register the route


app.listen(port);

app.use(function(req, res) {
// The snippet bellow helps to redirect and respond whenever a wrong 
route is entered on the site.
 res.status(404).send({url: req.originalUrl + ' not found'})
});

console.log('todo list RESTful API server started on: ' + port);
```

[my aws set up is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIeiB.png)

Answer (score -1):

The first time you try to run the application, the port you are using is not turned off, so when you run it, the port is in use. You can turn off the port and try again or change the port.

I would recommend you to experiment using Nodemon.

Nodemon will monitor our application and automatically restart the server when we see a change in any file. when the application closes the port itself.